# Extent user table of asp.net identity 2.0

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I have a web api 2 application in which I used asp.net identity 2.0 and Entity framework. In my MySql Database I add this table **ajt_collaborator**

```
CREATE TABLE `ajt_collaborator` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `marital_status` enum('M','MLLE','MME') DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` text,
  `Nom` text,
  `Prenom` text,
  `id_user_fk` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `deletion_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `collaborator_user_fk` (`id_user_fk`),
  CONSTRAINT `collaborator_user_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user_fk`) REFERENCES `aspnetusers` (`Id`)
)
```

which refers to **aspnetusers**

```
CREATE TABLE `aspnetusers` (
  `Id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `Hometown` text,
  `Email` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmailConfirmed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `PasswordHash` text,
  `SecurityStamp` text,
  `PhoneNumber` text,
  `PhoneNumberConfirmed` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `TwoFactorEnabled` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `LockoutEndDateUtc` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LockoutEnabled` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `AccessFailedCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
)
```

I need to merge these table in the second table and make additional properties of `aspnetusers` recognized in the application.

1. Is it possible to do that?
2. what the steps to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you want to merge ajt_collaborator to AspNetUsers.**

You can add additional properties to ApplicationUser entity class mirroring fields from ajt_collaborator table.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //...

    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

*You will find that AspNetUser table columns are defined in generic IdentityUser as properties.*

This will add new fields to AspNetUsers table when schema will be recreated.
Or you can use migrations without the need to recreate schema. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

**If you want to merge AspNetUsers to ajt_collaborator.**

Then you can map ApplicationUser to ajt_collaborator table.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    //...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("ajt_collaborator");
    }
}
```

Once again, adding required properties to the ApplicationUser entity class to mirror columns in ajt_collaborator table.